Got SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' error when runing TS script by ts-node
I am trying to generate React SVG icons components by using below TS script:
scripts/generate.ts:
import * as path from 'path';
import * as iconDefs from '../src/components';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { promisify } from 'util';
import { template } from 'lodash';

const writeFile = promisify(fs.writeFile);

type IconDefinitionWithIdentifier = {
  svgIdentifier: string;
  iconDef: React.ComponentType;
};

function walk<T>(fn: (iconDef: IconDefinitionWithIdentifier) => Promise<T>) {
  return Promise.all(
    Object.keys(iconDefs).map((svgIdentifier) => {
      const iconDef = (iconDefs as { [id: string]: React.ComponentType })[svgIdentifier];

      return fn({ svgIdentifier, iconDef });
    }),
  );
}

async function generateIcons() {
  const iconsDir = path.join(__dirname, '../src/icons');
  try {
    await promisify(fs.access)(iconsDir);
  } catch {
    await promisify(fs.mkdir)(iconsDir);
  }

  const render = template(
    `
      import React from 'react';
      import { DMIcon, DMIconProps } from '../dm-icon';

      const <%= svgIdentifier %> = (props: DMIconProps) => {
        return <DMIcon {...props} icon={<%= iconDef %>} />;
      }

      export default <%= svgIdentifier %>;
    `.trim(),
  );

  await walk(async (item) => {
    await writeFile(path.resolve(__dirname, `../src/icons/${item.svgIdentifier}.tsx`), render(item));
  });
}

generateIcons();

scripts/tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "preserve",
  },
}

package.json:
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
  "generate:step2": "rimraf ./src/icons && cross-env TS_NODE_PROJECT=scripts/tsconfig.json node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --loader ts-node/esm scripts/generate.ts"
},
/** other configs **/

Got below error:
$ npm run generate:step2
npm warn ignoring workspace config at D:\workspace\mrdulin\dm-icons\packages\icons-react/.npmrc

> @d-matrix/icons-react@0.0.6 generate:step2
> rimraf ./src/icons && cross-env TS_NODE_PROJECT=scripts/tsconfig.json node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --loader ts-node/esm scripts/generate.ts

(node:19928) ExperimentalWarning: `--experimental-loader` may be removed in the future; instead use `register()`:--import 'data:text/javascript,import { register } from "node:module"; import { pathToFileURL } from "node:url"; register("ts-node/esm", pathToFileURL("./"));'
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:19928) ExperimentalWarning: The Node.js specifier resolution flag is experimental. It could change or be removed at any time.
(node:19928) ExperimentalWarning: The Node.js specifier resolution flag is experimental. It could change or be removed at any time.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
file:///D:/workspace/mrdulin/dm-icons/packages/icons-react/src/components/excel.tsx:14
    return (<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" aria-labelledby={titleId} {...props}>
            ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at ModuleLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:152:18)
    at ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:299:14)

Node.js v18.20.3

src/components/excel.tsx:
import type { SVGProps } from "react";
interface SVGRProps {
  title?: string;
  titleId?: string;
}
const SvgExcel = ({
  title,
  titleId,
  ...props
}: SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> & SVGRProps) => (
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="1em"
    height="1em"
    viewBox="0 0 16 16"
    fill="currentColor"
    aria-hidden="true"
    focusable="false"
    aria-labelledby={titleId}
    {...props}
  >
    {title ? <title id={titleId}>{title}</title> : null}
    <g fill="none" fillRule="nonzero">
      <path d="M0 0h16v16H0z" />
      <path
        fill="#0E512B"
        d="M14.957 9.043H1.043L0 7.653 1.391 6.26H14.61L16 7.652z"
      />
      <path
        fill="#E6E6E6"
        d="M13.913 16H2.087a.695.695 0 0 1-.696-.696V.696c0-.385.312-.696.696-.696h8.348l4.174 4.174v11.13a.695.695 0 0 1-.696.696"
      />
      <path fill="#B3B3B3" d="M10.435 0v3.478c0 .385.311.696.695.696h3.479z" />
      <path
        fill="#1B7343"
        d="M15.304 13.913H.696A.695.695 0 0 1 0 13.217V7.652h16v5.565a.695.695 0 0 1-.696.696"
      />
      <path
        fill="#FFF"
        d="M5.771 12.174h-.854l-.532-.854-.527.854h-.835l.906-1.398-.852-1.334h.819l.493.845.474-.845h.843l-.865 1.392zM6.078 12.174V9.442h.738v2.136h1.051v.596zM10.09 11.344q0 .255-.129.451a.84.84 0 0 1-.371.307q-.243.11-.57.11-.272 0-.458-.04a1.7 1.7 0 0 1-.385-.133v-.657q.211.108.44.169.226.06.418.06.165 0 .24-.057a.18.18 0 0 0 .077-.146q0-.057-.03-.098a.4.4 0 0 0-.1-.085 4 4 0 0 0-.363-.176 1.7 1.7 0 0 1-.4-.235.7.7 0 0 1-.198-.262.9.9 0 0 1-.065-.35.7.7 0 0 1 .275-.588q.275-.21.755-.21.423 0 .865.195l-.226.57q-.384-.175-.662-.175-.143 0-.209.05a.15.15 0 0 0-.065.125q0 .081.083.144.082.063.451.232.353.16.49.34a.74.74 0 0 1 .137.46M12.973 12.174h-.854l-.532-.854-.527.854h-.835l.906-1.398-.852-1.334h.819l.493.845.474-.845h.843l-.865 1.392z"
      />
    </g>
  </svg>
);
export default SvgExcel;

I expect the generated SVG icon component like:
import React from 'react';
import { DMIcon, DMIconProps } from '../dm-icon';

const Excel = (props: DMIconProps) => {
  return <DMIcon {...props} icon={SvgExcel} />;
}

export default Excel;

GitHub Repo
Related question: ts-node and svg import gives: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
Related discussion: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/discussions/1965

You need jsx: react. Otherwise you will get JSX in the .js output, and of-course, nodejs cannot execute it.
Fixed tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
  },
}

